# Correct way to reference an existing openid provider in a role to be created using terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services

```
openid provider was created as a standalone in a Staging account.


resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "github_oidc_github_actions" {
  url = "https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com"

  client_id_list = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]

  thumbprint_list = ["a031c46782e6e6c662c2c87c76da9aa62ccabd8e"]

}
```

This role need to be created also in Staging account.The reason the openid provider and the role was not created at the same time is because i need to be able to call the below terraform code to create different roles then attach to the already created openId provider.My question is how can i reference the already created openid provider ARN in the Federated section so that whenever a role is created the openid assume role will be attached to them

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "GitHubActions_role" {
  name = var.role_name

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Principal":{
        "Federated":"${How can i reference the already created openid provider arn here}"
      },
      "Condition":{
        "StringEquals": {
          "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike":{
          "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": [
            "repo:ipipeline/${var.repo_name}:ref:refs/heads/${var.branch_name}",
            "repo:ipipeline/${var.repo_name}:pull_request"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using data source to get the information about the role?

Comment: No,I am not.The OpenID provider was created using terraform code in a different folder.I want to be able to reference the already created OpenID provider ARN in my staging account in all the roles that will be created for Federation

Comment: Do you have its arn? Its not really clear what is the issue? Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes but i am thinking there is a better way to reference it as i create more roles that will use it without hardcoding the ARN